# Boost lambda bewilderment

Tags: c++, boost-bind, boost-lambda

Why is callback called once only?

```
bool callback()
{
    static bool res = false;
    res = !res;
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<int> x(10);

    bool result=false;
    for_each(x.begin(),x.end(),var(result)=var(result)||bind(callback));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `||` expression [**short circuits**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) after the first time `bind` returns `true`.

The first time you evaluate

```
result = result || bind(...)  // result is false at this point
```

`bind` is called, because that's the only way to determine the value of `false || bind(...)`.  Because `bind(...)` returns `true`, `result` is set to `true`.

Every other time you say

```
result = result || bind(...)  // result is true at this point
```

... **the `bind(...)` expression isn't evaluated, because it doesn't matter what it returns**; the expression `true || anything` is always `true`, and the `||` expression [**short circuits**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

One way to ensure that `bind` is always called would be to move it to the left side of the `||`, or change the `||` to an `&&`, depending on what you are trying to accomplish with `result`.

Comment: And that's because Boost.Lambda's operator|| is specially designed to be short-circuiting in conjunction with the delayed-execution ability of the functor object that bind() returns. An ordinary overloaded operator|| does NOT short-circuit.

Comment: yeah, that's a nice feature of it. usually if you overload operator||, short circuit does not happen. boost lambda seems to take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example, Boost.Lambda doesn't really gain you anything. Get rid of the lambda parts, and maybe you'll see more clearly what's going on:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  result = result || callback();
```

This still relies on you to know that the `||` operator is short-circuited, as [Daniel explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664273/boost-lambda-bewilderment/664289#664289).